# Modal instantly closing by outside modal content click event handler function (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have the `App` component that has a **Open Modal** button to open a modal by setting `isModalOpen` state to true.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";

const App = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={openModal}>Open Modal</button>
      {isModalOpen && <Modal onClose={closeModal} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`Modal` component takes `closeModal` function that sets `isModalOpen` state to false to close the modal. This component contains a `useEffect()` hook to register a click event handler `handleOutsideClick` to the window to detect outside `.modal-content` click and close the modal.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Modal = ({ onClose }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
      if (!event.target.closest(".modal-content")) {
        console.log("closing modal");
        onClose();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    };
  }, [onClose]);

  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <h1>Modal Content</h1>
        <button onClick={onClose}>Close Modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

The problem is, whenever I click **Open Modal** button to open the modal. The `handleOutsideClick` event handler in the `Modal` component is also executed and modal closes instantly.

Expeceted behaviour: When I click **Open Modal**, modal should open. When I click outside `modal-content`, modal should be closed.

Comment: do you have a runnable demonstration of this - such as on a site like codepen? Looking at your code I don't think what you are describing should happen, because the event listener that closes the modal on click will not be registered until the modal component has opened, by which point the click has already happened. I could be wrong but, without a live example to play with, it's hard to say more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**: So one think that keeps me thinking about is the `click` event so I checked the docs and the Github issue I found [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24657). Look like React intentionally run the `handleOutsideClick()` on the first render of `Modal`.

So `One possible workaround is to delay the subscription with a zero timeout` (check out the full answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24657#issuecomment-1150119055)) and in this case, just simple add `setTimeout` to `addEventListenter`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
});
```

<strike>You need to change the event from `click` to `mousedown` inside useEffect of `Modal`:</strike>

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
      console.log(event.target);
      if (!event.target.closest(".modal-content")) {
        console.log("closing modal");
        onClose();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick); // change here

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick); // change here
    };
  }, [onClose]);
```

It's because of the event firing different (you can read about it more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20This%20differs%20from%20the%20click%20event%20in%20that%20click%20is%20fired%20after%20a%20full%20click%20action%20occurs%3B%20that%20is%2C%20the%20mouse%20button%20is%20pressed%20and%20released%20while%20the%20pointer%20remains%20inside%20the%20same%20element.%20mousedown%20is%20fired%20the%20moment%20the%20button%20is%20initially%20pressed.)):

- When you use `click`: the `handleOutsideClick` will run after the `click` event of openmodal so the modal will be closed immediately
- When you use `mousedown`: it will run as you expected.

  Hope this explaination can help.